# Plotting factor-by-curve tensor product smooths of mgcv::gam

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

So I have a statistical model in which I am using factor-by-curves, i.e., fitting separate smoothing curves for some categories, as in the following. (I'm not paying much attention to the data/model's meaning, just using it as a minimal example.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(qgam)
library(mgcv)
data(UKload)
test <- gam(
  NetDemand ~ te(wM, Posan, by = Year), 
  data = UKload %>% mutate(Year = as.factor(Year))
)
```

When I was simply doing smoothing curves by `s` instead of tensors, I was happy to use `visreg` package as follows:

```
library(visreg)
test2 <- gam(
  NetDemand ~ s(wM, by = Year),
  data = UKload %>% mutate(Year = as.factor(Year))
)
visreg(test2, xvar = "wM", by = "Year")
```

[image]

However, I don't seem to be able to do something similar when I am including a tensor---it will simply draw a contour plot with full data, instead of having it partitioned by the factor variable of interest:

```
visreg2d(test, xvar = "wM", yvar = "Posan", by = "Year")
```

> Warning message:
>   In title(...) : "by" is not a graphical parameter

[image]

I can do the `mgcv::vis.gam` with a condition:

```
vis.gam(test, plot.type = "contour", cond = list(Year = 2011))
```

and later aggregate the plots by `Rmisc::multiplot` or base `plot`, but I'm not too happy with these solutions, both in terms of aesthetics and the workflow. Any handy tips on making pretty plots for tensor product smooths with factor-by-curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you mean by prettier? ;-)

My *gratia* package will produce plots of factor-by smooths. For example

```
draw(test, ncol = 2)
```

produces

[image]

The grey parts of the surfaces are where one would be extrapolating too far from the available data. How far is "too far" is controlled by the `dist` argument, which by default is set to mark any point on the grid as `NA` if it is more than 10% (`dist = 0.1`) of the range of the data away from the nearest data point.

I haven't got round to allowing these surfaces to be plotted on the same scale and to having a common colourbar legend, but *gratia* is very much a work in progress.

If you want to do the plotting yourself, then *gratia* can also produce a tidy-like object (a tibble, with data arranged in a form suitable for plotting with *ggplot2*) via the `evaluate_smooth()` function

```
> es <- evaluate_smooth(test, smooth = 'te(wM,Posan)')
> es
# A tibble: 60,000 x 7
   smooth                by_variable     wM   Posan   est    se Year 
   <chr>                 <fct>        <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
 1 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year        -1.43  0.00137 7556. 1516. 2011 
 2 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year        -1.11  0.00137 7506. 1466. 2011 
 3 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year        -0.789 0.00137 7456. 1417. 2011 
 4 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year        -0.470 0.00137 7405. 1368. 2011 
 5 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year        -0.150 0.00137 7355. 1319. 2011 
 6 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year         0.169 0.00137 7305. 1271. 2011 
 7 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year         0.489 0.00137 7255. 1224. 2011 
 8 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year         0.808 0.00137 7205. 1178. 2011 
 9 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year         1.13  0.00137 7154. 1132. 2011 
10 te(wM,Posan):Year2011 Year         1.45  0.00137 7104. 1087. 2011 
# … with 59,990 more rows
```

Here you can see that there are variables coding the particular smooth, an indication of what the `by` variable is, and all the data columns associate with the surfaces shown above. Here `wM` and `Posan` are evaluated on a 100x100 grid of points over the range of the data before evaluating the smooth at those combinations of covariates.

Comment: Thank you, that was simple enough! It definitely meets the "prettier" criteria.